# What is wrong in this php session code? "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file"

Tags: php, session

```
if ($_SESSION['raza'] == 'Humano') {
           $defensaraza = 10 + $defensa;
           $magiaraza = 5 + $magia;
           $iniciativaraza = 5 + $iniciativa;
           $ataqueraza = $ataque + $entrenamientomelee[$edcuerpoacuerpo]['nivel'] * 0.5;
           $balisticaraza = $balistica + $entrenamientobalistico[$edbalistica]['nivel'] * 0.5;
           ?>
          <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" ><?php echo 'Ataque: +' . $ataqueraza . '%' ?></span>
          <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" ><?php echo 'Balistica: +' . $balistica . '%' ?></span>
         <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" > <?php echo 'Magia: +' . $magiaraza . '%' ?></span>
            <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" ><?php echo 'Defensa: +' . $defensaraza . '%' ?></span>
            <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" ><?php echo 'Iniciativa: +' . $iniciativaraza . '' ?></span>
    <?php
    }

    if ($_SESSION['raza'] == 'Orco') {

        $defensaraza = 10 + $defensa;
        $magiaraza = 5 + $magia;
        $iniciativaraza = -5 + $iniciativa;
        $ataqueraza = 10 + $ataque + $entrenamientomelee[$edcuerpoacuerpo]['nivel'] * 0.5;
        $balisticaraza = $balistica + $entrenamientobalistico[$edbalistica]['nivel'] * 0.5;
        ?>
          <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" ><?php echo 'Ataque: +' . $ataqueraza . '%'; ?></span>
          <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" ><?php echo 'Balistica: +' . $balistica . '%'; ?></span>
         <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" > <?php echo 'Magia: +' . $magiaraza . '%'; ?></span>
            <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" ><?php echo 'Defensa: +' . $defensaraza . '%'; ?></span>
            <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" ><?php echo 'Iniciativa: +' . $iniciativaraza; ?></span>

<?php } ?>
```

If I have it the next way it's all right:

```
if ($_SESSION['raza'] == 'Humano') {
           $defensaraza = 10 + $defensa;
           $magiaraza = 5 + $magia;
           $iniciativaraza = 5 + $iniciativa;
           $ataqueraza = $ataque + $entrenamientomelee[$edcuerpoacuerpo]['nivel'] * 0.5;
           $balisticaraza = $balistica + $entrenamientobalistico[$edbalistica]['nivel'] * 0.5;
           ?>
          <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" ><?php echo 'Ataque: +' . $ataqueraza . '%' ?></span>
          <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" ><?php echo 'Balistica: +' . $balistica . '%' ?></span>
         <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" > <?php echo 'Magia: +' . $magiaraza . '%' ?></span>
            <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" ><?php echo 'Defensa: +' . $defensaraza . '%' ?></span>
            <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" ><?php echo 'Iniciativa: +' . $iniciativaraza . '' ?></span>
    <?php
    }?>
```

I tried also putting else if and checked all openings and closings of php but i don't get why this error is happening to me, only with session. Session is 100% started at this point, and it goes right if it's on the first IF, even if I change 'humano' to another name of session, the problem is the second if.
Help please.

Comment: This block of code alone does not have a parse error. The session has nothing to do with it because PHP is not even attempting to actually _run_ the code; it fails before then.  Before or after this, you must have another syntax problem, which is likely an unclosed `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your php tags looks awkward and somehow either your braces or open and close php tags are not matching up. Luckily there is a much better/cleaner way.[PHP Alternate Syntax for control stuctures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Something like this:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['raza'] == 'Orco'): ?>
<?php
    $defensaraza = 10 + $defensa;
    $magiaraza = 5 + $magia;
    $iniciativaraza = -5 + $iniciativa;
    $ataqueraza = 10 + $ataque + $entrenamientomelee[$edcuerpoacuerpo]['nivel'] * 0.5;
    $balisticaraza = $balistica + $entrenamientobalistico[$edbalistica]['nivel'] * 0.5;
?>
   <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" ><?php echo 'Ataque: +' . $ataqueraza . '%' ?></span>
   <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" ><?php echo 'Balistica: +' . $balistica . '%' ?></span>
   <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" > <?php echo 'Magia: +' . $magiaraza . '%' ?></span>
   <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" ><?php echo 'Defensa: +' . $defensaraza . '%' ?></span>
   <span style="display:block; font-size:17px" ><?php echo 'Iniciativa: +' . $iniciativaraza . '' ?></span>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Give that a shot.

Comment: Good job! Worked! I don't know why this happens but this is the answer! Can't give upvotes but 100% working! Ty!

Comment: You can upvote this answer @joshtramposo as well as accept it by clicking the big checkmark next to it.

Comment: True, now i see i have to wait some minutes to press the checkmark. I'll do it! Thanks!